# what is better view or another table in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I got table that I need to search by not indexed field. What is better, to make separate table with data I need and indexed by that field or make view? what is drawbacks of each chose? May be I can use secondary Index in that case instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A second table will be better hands down. Only disadvantage is it requires more of your effort.

Materialized views have issues where they get outta sync and theres no way to repair them, only drop and recreate (they are now considered experimental and not prod ready). Secondary indexes require huge scatter gather queries that make your 99th percentile your average (while also being difficult to size appropriately). Ultimately for any heavy load, MVs or 2i will break, but its easy to add.

Comment: Is write time to base table with MV will be higher? I don't quit understand that moment from docs.

Comment: MVs are pretty efficient. The problem is under some scenarios they can become inaccurate and theres no way to check or fix it. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10346